# MySQL Syntax errors in trigger with REPLACE()

Tags: mysql, replace, triggers, syntax-error

I'll apologize first if this question has already been answered, I tried a search and was unable to locate this specific question.  I am attempting to create two triggers that will look for a specific string pattern in the field called 'keyword' and replace it with a different one.  I have worked with this now for several hours and don't have any hair left.  Can someone tell me what it is I am doing wrong?

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER override_new_alias
BEFORE INSERT ON url_alias
Begin
    set NEW.keyword = replace(NEW.keyword, "store-", "store/");
    set NEW.keyword = replace(NEW.keyword, "genre-", "genre/");
    set NEW.keyword = replace(NEW.keyword, "author-", "author/");
End$$
DELIMITER ;


DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER override_edit_alias
AFTER update ON url_alias
Begin
    set OLD.keyword = replace(OLD.keyword, "store-", "store/");
    set OLD.keyword = replace(OLD.keyword, "genre-", "genre/");
    set OLD.keyword = replace(OLD.keyword, "author-", "author/");
End$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Here is what I get.....

MySQL said: Documentation

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Begin
    set NEW.keyword = replace(NEW.keyword, "store-", "store/");
    set NEW.ke' at line 3
```

Thanks ahead of time.

Answer (score 2):

## FIRST TRIGGER

You forgot `FOR EACH ROW` in the first trigger

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER override_new_alias
BEFORE INSERT ON url_alias
FOR EACH ROW
Begin
    set NEW.keyword = replace(NEW.keyword, "store-", "store/");
    set NEW.keyword = replace(NEW.keyword, "genre-", "genre/");
    set NEW.keyword = replace(NEW.keyword, "author-", "author/");
End$$
DELIMITER ;
```

## SECOND TRIGGER

Please note that you cannot replace any values in an AFTER UPDATE since all changed columns are committed. Even if the AFTER UPDATE trigger compiles, it will fail on execution. Why ?

According to [**the Book**](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596100892)

[image: MySQL Stored Procedure Programming]

Chapter 11 Page 251 Paragraph 3 says the following:

> The most significant difference between `BEFORE` and `AFTER` triggers is that in an `AFTER` you are not able to modify the values  about to be inserted into or updated with the table in question -- the DML has executed, and it is too late to try to change what the DML is going to do.